# How to send a character type value from an application to another on progress4gl?

Tags: parameters, parameter-passing, progress-4gl

I've been trying to use `define input/output parameter <variable> as character no-undo` to send/receive some value, I've searched on many forums but I still can't get it to work it compiles but I get an error while trying to run it.

May someone provide me an explanation that would clarify what I'm doing wrong?

P.S.: I'm still a newbie at progress4gl.

***This is the application that receives***:

```
define input parameter vparam as character no-undo.

put unformatted "Data:".
put unformatted vparam.
```

***This is the application that sends***:

```
define output parameter vparam as character no-undo.

assign vparam = "It works!".
```

***Error while trying to run it:***

> Mismatched number of parameters passed to routine
>
> [path to my app] myApp(it happens to both apps).ped (3234)

Both applications are in the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what it's supposed to look like:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE chVar   AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
ASSIGN chVar = "TEST".
RUN test(chVar).

PROCEDURE Test:
DEFINE INPUT PARAMETER chParm   AS CHARACTER    NO-UNDO.

MESSAGE chParm
   VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTON OK.

END PROCEDURE.
```

The code for a .p program looks similar:

```
/* Program.p */
DEFINE INPUT PARAMETER chParm   AS CHARACTER    NO-UNDO.
MESSAGE chParm
   VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTON OK.

RETURN.
```

and the way to call this procedure:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE chVar   AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
ASSIGN chVar = "TEST".
RUN Program.p(chVar).
```

For INPUT-OUTPUT parameters - you'd change the DEFINE PARAMETER and the call, like so:

```
/* Program.p */
DEFINE INPUT-OUTPUT PARAMETER chParm   AS CHARACTER    NO-UNDO.
MESSAGE chParm
   VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTON OK.

RETURN.
```

and the way to call this procedure:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE chVar   AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
ASSIGN chVar = "TEST".
RUN Program.p(INPUT-OUTPUT chVar).
```

Comment: Oh, it works, it requires way more than I thought, thanks for providing a well explained answer +1

Comment: It is a bit "chatty" - though nothing a macro can't solve. Glad it answered your question!